# Apache RewriteRule throwing Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache 2.4.18 with a self-signed SSL certificate (working OK) in a local virtualhost, and using this `.htaccess` configuration throws HTTP 500 error:

`Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/users/edit/([^/]*)$ /admin/users/edit/edit.php?user=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`

The error is shown only in the "edit page", not in every page.

`https://mydomain.dev/admin/users/edit/3`

I've use the same rewrite logic previously without any conflict, so I can't identify the error.

The Apache SSL error log for that virtualhost has this log:

`[core:error] [pid 1257] [client 127.0.0.1:50669] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://mydomain.dev/admin/users/`

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a rewrite loop error. The problem is with your Rewrite pattern **^admin/users/edit/([^/]*)$** as it also matches the Rule's target **admin/users/edit/edit.php**  . You need to exclude the destination path from your rule, put the following Condition above your RewriteRule line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/users/edit/edit\.php$ [NC]
```

You can also fix it using a negitive lookahead based regex pattern :

```
^admin/users/edit/((?!edit\.php).*)$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand the issue but none of the commands you provided worked for me. Both throw 404 error when I access to `https://mydomain.dev/admin/users/edit/3`

Comment: I just move `/users/edit/edit.php` to `/users/edit.php` and change this: `RewriteRule ^admin/users/edit/([^/]*)$ /admin/users/edit.php?user=$1` So now is working as expected :) Thanks for helping me to understand what was creating that loop!